# How can I run a Hello world c++ code using python

Tags: python, c++

I want to know how can I create a python script that run c++ code.

I did find some talks about subprocess module but it's used to run commands 
I did find some talks about Boost and Swig but I didn't understand as a beginner how to use them

Testing subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["g++", "main.cpp"],shell = True)
tmp=subprocess.call("main.cpp",shell = True)
print("printing result")
print(tmp)
```

Can any one help me please!

Comment: When you compile a C++ source file, the output is a binary.  `g++` by default will write that to `a.out` unless you specify a different target with `-o` option.  You certainly do not execute the C++ source file itself.

Comment: Can you suggueste to me an exemple please !

Comment: example: `subprocess.call("a.out", shell=True)`

Comment: You should also check the return code from `g++` to make sure it succeeded.  If there are errors, the output won't exist or if it does it'll be from a previous successful compilation.

Comment: Python will never directly execute C++ code (well, there are library bindings I suppose...) so you are talking about writing a script in Python to automate the C++ compile/run cycle? What is it, in context, that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create a python script that can run c++ code

Comment: Python can't run directly C++, you would have to create parser and interpreter for C++. It can execute C++ compiled to machine code (.exe file) - and you already did it. You compiled C++ to machine code using `g++ main.cpp` and you should get machine code in file `a.out` and now you can execute it `subprocess.call("a.out", shell=True)`.

Comment: @ITWorld That's just repeating the question's opener. I'm asking for more detail, more context, more explanation of what you're trying to do and why. What is your goal? "Run C++ code" in what way? What sort of C++ code? Why should Python do this? In what manner? To accomplish what? We cannot adequately answer your question without the proper context.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So what I am trying to is to run c++ functions or files code using a python script. Why or for what? It's something that I don't know either because my boss who know the reason. He's the one who need it and ask me to search how to do it
He did not specify why or for what so I can't answer that question

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to get a more detailed requirements specification from your boss, because at present you do not have sufficient information to properly complete your task. _"run c++ functions or files code using a python script"_ is extremely vague.

Answer (score 5):

A simple example would be to create a `.cpp` file:

```
// cpy.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World! from C++" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And a Python script:

```
// cpy.py
import subprocess
cmd = "cpy.cpp"
subprocess.call(["g++", cmd])
subprocess.call("./a.out")
```

Then in the terminal, run the Python script:

```
~ python cpy.py
~ Hello World! from C++
```

**EDIT:**

If you want control of calling C++ functions from Python, you will need to create bindings to extend Python with C++. This can be done a number of ways, the Python docs has a thorough raw implementation of how it can be done for simple cases, but also there are libraries such as pybind and boost.Python that can do this for you.

An example with boost.Python:

```
// boost-example.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int printHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World! from C++" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
        def("print_hello", printHello);
}
```

You will need to create a shared object file (.so) and make sure to link the appropriate Python headers and libraries. An example might look like:

```
g++ printHello.cpp -fPIC -shared -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -lboost_python -o hello.so
```

And in the same directory that you created the `hello.so` file:

```
python
>>> import hello
>>> hello.print_hello()
Hello, World! from C++
```

Boost.Python can be used to do some pretty magic things, including exposing classes, wrapping overloaded functions, exposing global and class variables for reading and writing, hybrid Python/C++ inheritance heirarchies, all with the utility of dramatic performance gains.
I recommend going through [these](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html) docs and getting to know the API if you are looking to go down this route.

Comment: Why do you compile on the commandline if your script does it too?

Comment: Yes true, only one is necessary

Comment: I want to run c++ code using python script and not call a command that run the .exe file

Comment: Do you mean that you want a c++ function eg. foo in a class bar that you can use in python like , import bar; bar.foo() ?

Comment: Will you update the answer then to remove the excess compilation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure thing

Comment: @ITWorld I have added an example with boost python, take a look

Comment: @jackw11111 Thank you for your example, but the boost folder has to be in my project folder or where ? Because I did put it in "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\boost" but I have an error pointing on #include <boost/python.hpp> that says it didn't find the file

Comment: @ITWorld You might need to link to the folder where the header files when you compile something like `g++ -I C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages` etc ...

Comment: @jackw11111 I had the error "ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did use ctypes instead

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to compiling the C++ code into a separate program and executing that, you can also use cppyy (http://cppyy.org) to run the C++ code directly, through a JIT, within the same program.

Example:

```
import cppyy
cppyy.cppdef('''
void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}''')
cppyy.gbl.hello()   # calls the C++ function 'hello' defined above
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .os module of python to run os commands.

```
import os
myCmd1 = 'ls -la'
os.system(myCmd)
```

Your command can be 'g++ main.cpp second.cpp -o run', then you can use the same mechanism to call the `./run` shell.

Make sure you have the right permissions

Comment: Also worth testing the the ages of the cpp file and the executable. If the executable is newer than the cpp file, there's not much point to recompiling the cpp file. On second thought, this assumes stable monotonic time.

Comment: Can you suggueste to me an example  please ! Or if you know where i can find a simple tutorial please !

Comment: @ITWorld this specific case isn't the sort of thing where you are likely to find a tutorial. You should be able to find a general tutorial for running external processes, and you'll have to adapt from there.

Comment: @bem22 I want to run c++ code using python script and not call a command that run the .exe file

Comment: When you said run C++ code I assumed you want to run C++ compiled code. My answer describes how you can compile and run the code. This requires the GNU g++ compiler and a unix environment. What I suggested was a solution that only runs in Unix or bash supporting systems. Basically ./ means "run this script". You can run different scripts: For example ./hello where ./hello is the output from g++ of hello.cpp (you compile it by using the following command: g++ -o hello hello.cpp)

Comment: @bem22 yes but it's not answering the whole question.
Is there a way to convert a c++ to python or run a c++ using python without using commands

Comment: It is virtually impossible. C has many features that Python does not, such as pointers, access to direct syscalls and file descriptors etc.